# Android build flavors - Set buildConfigField value to null

Tags: android

I have a template app which has many build flavors, In one of my flavors I want to set one of the buildConfigFields to null, how can I do it?

I tried setting it like this:

`buildConfigField "String", "EasterEggURL", null`

But it says that it cannot be null.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you try?

```
buildConfigField "String", "EasterEggURL", "null"
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be :

```
buildConfigField "String", "EasterEggURL", 'null'
```

Notice the `''` that surrounds the `null` value.